# Create trigger for different inserts

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have different tables

1. bookings(id,lesson_id,user_id)
2. Lessons(id,name,date,start_time,end_time,max_enrollments,enrollments)
3. Permits(user_id,membership_id,used_entries,valid_until,entries)

How can I create a trigger that increments the `enrollments`(table lessons) and `entries` of table permits every time a new record is added in bookings
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I create a trigger"? Have you had a look at the official documentation? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *[Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers)*

Regist your observer on `AppServiceProvider` and then create a observer with this code:

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Booking;
use App\Lessons;
use App\Permit;

class BookObserver
{
    /**
     * Listen to the Booking created event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Booking  $books
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Booking $books)
    {
        Lessons::find($books->lesson_id)->increment('enrollments');
    }
}
```

Regist the observer in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` by adding this line on `boot`

```
Booking::observe(BookObserver::class);
```

Don't forget to call your model and observer:

```
use App\Booking;
use App\Observers\BookObserver;
```

Comment: how you you do it for the enrollments,class Booking 
 public function lesson()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\Lesson::class, 'lessons_id');
 }

Comment: just like that return public function lesson() { $this->belongsTo('\App\Models\Lesson'); }. That should work

Comment: I dont get it just insert function lesson inside created?

Comment: How do you know the OP is Eloquent question is not tagged as such?

Comment: @JamesMoore Myad, didn't understood your question. I edit my answer

Comment: let me try and I will say what happens

Comment: @P.Salmon you are right, didn't thought about that. But in the comments he just shown that he was using eloquent (with relation belongsTo)

Comment: cannot make static method

Comment: @JamesMoore what method?

Comment: method created,I inserted it int the booking model

Comment: no, you have to create one file (the observer that i show you in the awnser) and register it in file AppServiceProvider. Only that way the framework will understand that the observer points to the model.
check oficial docs

Comment: this is not working in my Booking Model I added  
 use App\Observers\BookObserver;,in the appservice provider         Booking::observe(BookObserver::class);
 and in the bookobserver : `code public function creating(Booking $books)
    {
        Lesson::find($books->lessons_id)->increment('enrollments');

        Permit::decrement('entries', 1);
    }`

Comment: This question is tagged `mysql` and `sql`.  This is none of that.  What is this? PHP?

Comment: @mikeb i think it was edited, i saw it as laravel (PHP framework) at the first place. My answer is laravel

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing that, I would aggregate when you need the data.  i.e. instead of managing the state of the `Lessons.enrollments` and `Permits.entries` calculate them with a query when you need them:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Bookings B WHERE B.user_id = ? and B.lession_id = ?`

That gets you a count of bookings for a user and lesson

Then:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Permits P WHERE P.user_id = ?`

That gets you a count of entries for a user

This way, you do not have to worry about keeping the values that you can calculate up-to-date separately, which will be easier to manage as you know you have the latest numbers from the queries.

Create indexes correctly (on the `Permits.user_id` and the `Bookings.user_id` and `Bookings.lesson_id` (or, even better, a compound index on both `Bookings` columns)) and those queries will be very fast.

Comment: the truth is I already do it this way but sb told me it is very bad ,I was like ...

Comment: What do you mean sb told you it was very bad?  What is sb?